# C++ Visual studio compiler warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following piece of code throwing **warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)**. Moving #define true and false after string and map header inclusions not throwing this warning. This is a sample code and in the actual code #define true and false are defined in one of our product library header files. So I want to understand why this warning is thrown by visual studio and why it is going away when #define moved after string and map header inclusions.

```
#ifndef true
#define true    1
#endif

#ifndef false
#define false   0
#endif

#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> pair;
    pair.insert(std::make_pair("Key1", "Value1"));
    return 0;
}
```

Full details of warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\utility(144): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1801) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool>::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,int,void>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Other1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>>>
1>  ,            _Other2=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1801) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool>::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,int,void>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Other1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>>>
1>  ,            _Other2=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1160) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Insert_nohint<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>&,std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *>*>(bool,_Valty,_Nodety)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<std::string>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>
1>  ,            _Valty=std::pair<const std::string,std::string> &
1>  ,            _Nodety=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>,void *> *
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1160) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Insert_nohint<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>&,std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *>*>(bool,_Valty,_Nodety)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<std::string>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>
1>  ,            _Valty=std::pair<const std::string,std::string> &
1>  ,            _Nodety=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>,void *> *
1>          ]
1>          Source.cpp(41) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert<std::pair<const char *,const char *>>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<std::string>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>
1>  ,            _Valty=std::pair<const char *,const char *>
1>          ]
1>          Source.cpp(41) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert<std::pair<const char *,const char *>>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<std::string>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>
1>  ,            _Valty=std::pair<const char *,const char *>
1>          ]
```

Comment: The question is: why would you want to do this? Is it an academic question, or a real use-case? Because what you're doing is potentially *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: `#ifndef true` Why ? Where is this not defined ?

Comment: The headers contain code that uses the `true` and `false` **keywords**. Your macros replace them right under the standard library. Is it really not obvious why it's happening?

Comment: @juanchopanza As I said, the #defines are declared in one of our product header files(not written by me). Our product supports cross OS platform and it is a real use case. Am asked to fix this warning hence posted here

Comment: Well, your code isn't standard C++ compliant then. At least, as long as you use the standard library.

Comment: Your `#define` directives introduce undefined behaviour. `true` and `false` are C++ keywords. It is not allowed to `#define` identifiers identical to keywords.

Comment: `As I said, the #defines are declared in one of our product header files(not written by me)` Can you not `#undef` them then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not condoning your macros, but the answer to your question is that your check isn't nearly complete. In C++, `true` and `false` are keywords, not macros like in C's `stdbool.h` header. So checking if they aren't defined is always going to be true. If you want to C++-proof those macros, the condition should be something like this:

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(true)
#define true    1
#endif
```

`__cplusplus` is a standard macro that is defined by the implementation when a TU is compiled as C++. The added check will prevent messing up with those keywords, and breaking any standard library headers that use them.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> the #defines are declared in one of our product header files(not written by me)

Then, you should tell the guy who wrote this code to modify it. It's probably pure C code (where true/false are not defined) and he decided to declare them, why not, but then, I thing the good strategy would be for him not to use the standard names true/false that end up confliciting with standard ones in your case. He should use MyTrue/MyFalse (or whetever name that would make sense in the context).

So just (or ask him to) go in the code where true/false was defined, replace all occurence of "true" by "MyTrue", all "false" by "MyFalse", the code behaviour should not be impacted. The conflict will go away as well as the warning!